# Shards are not equally balanced in cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have 2 shards.
One is over standalone server and another over replicaset:

```
mongos> db.runCommand({listshards:1})
{
        "shards" : [
            {
                "_id" : "shard0000",
                "host" : "mongo3:10001"
            },
            {
                "_id" : "set1",
                "host" : "set1/mongo1:10001,mongo2:10001"
            }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I've inserted about 30M records.

As far as I understand mongo should balance equally the data between the shards, but it does not happen:

```
mongos> db.stats()
{
    "raw" : {
        "set1/mongo1:10001,mongo2:10001" : {
            "db" : "my_ginger",
            "collections" : 3,
            "objects" : 5308714,
            "avgObjSize" : 811.9953284354742,
            "dataSize" : 4310650968,
            "storageSize" : 4707774464,
            "numExtents" : 23,
            "indexes" : 2,
            "indexSize" : 421252048,
            "fileSize" : 10666115072,
            "nsSizeMB" : 16,
            "ok" : 1
        },
        "mongo3:10001" : {
            "db" : "my_ginger",
            "collections" : 6,
            "objects" : 25162626,
            "avgObjSize" : 1081.6777010475776,
            "dataSize" : 27217851444,
            "storageSize" : 28086624096,
            "numExtents" : 38,
            "indexes" : 6,
            "indexSize" : 1903266512,
            "fileSize" : 34276900864,
            "nsSizeMB" : 16,
            "ok" : 1
        }
    },
    "objects" : 30471340,
    "avgObjSize" : 1034.6936633571088,
    "dataSize" : 31528502412,
    "storageSize" : 32794398560,
    "numExtents" : 61,
    "indexes" : 8,
    "indexSize" : 2324518560,
    "fileSize" : 44943015936,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems that you have 3 unsharded collections. Did you insert a lot of documents into them?

Comment: What is the output of `sh.status()` from the mongos?

Comment: I have 3 unsharded collection but, they are almost empty ( 40 records)

Comment: mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: { "_id" : 1, "version" : 3 }
  shards:
 {  "_id" : "set1",  "host" : "set1/mongo1:10001,mongo2:10001" }
 {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "mongo3:10001" }
  databases:
 {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
 {  "_id" : "my_db",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
  my_db.query_data chunks:
    shard0000 164
    set1 85
   too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print

Comment: So everything is going into to shard0000. How did you create the following shard - **`            {
                "_id" : "set1",
                "host" : "set1/mongo1:10001,mongo2:10001"
            }`**

Comment: How did you shard your collections? `sh.status` is only indicating that shard0000 has any data.

Comment: Yes sure, db.runCommand( { addshard : "set1/mongo1:10001,mongo2:10001" } )    I've enabled sharding on database and sharded my collection as well as it's described here: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/operations/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the `sh.status()` output in the comments, you have 164 chunks on shard0000 (the single host) and 85 on set1 (the replica set).  There are a couple of common reasons that this kind of imbalance can happen:

1. You picked a bad shard key (monotonically increasing or similar)
2. All your data was initially on a single shard and is being rebalanced

The balancer will be continuously attempting to move chunks from the high shard to the low while at the same time moving the max-chunk around (for people that pick the aforementioned monotonically increasing keys, this helps).  However, there can only be one migration at the time, so this will take some time, especially if you continue writing/reading from the shards at the same time.  If things are really bad, and you did pick a poor shard key, then this may persist for some time.

If all your data was on one shard first, and then you added another, then you have a similar problem - it will take a while for the chunk count to stabilise because half the data has to be moved from the original shard (in addition to its other activities) to balance things out.  The balancer will pick low range chunks to move first in general, so if these are less likely to be in memory (back to the poor shard key again), then they will have to be paged in before they can be migrated.

To check the balancer is running:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.setBalancerState/#sh.getBalancerState

Then, to see what it has been up to, connect to a mongos (last 10 operations):

```
use config
db.changelog.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(10).pretty()
```

Similarly you will see messaging in the primary logs of each shard relating to the migrations, how long they are taking etc. if you want to see their performance.

Comment: Hi. The shard key is GUID that is randomly generated. I've just run a script that creates millions of entries with the same structure, but different GUID. When You say "some time" what time it's about ? Seconds, hours, days, weeks?

Comment: "some time" is a combination of various factors: how much of the data is in memory (it must be read in to be migrated), for the portion that is not in memory, how fast can it be paged in from disk, what the load is on the cluster (both reads on the source and writes on the target), how many documents per chunk (each one is essentially inserted on the target), the size of those docs, and the speed of the network between the machines (usually not an issue).  As such, it is impossible to estimate generally - it will also be faster at times when the cluster is less busy etc.